# Duplicate module imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, material-ui, bundler, parceljs

I'm creating an app using `Parcel` and `@material-ui/styles`. My app has the `@material-ui/styles` dependency. I'm also importing my own npm package that I store locally. This package has also the `@material-ui/styles` dependency but it's peer dependency. I would assume that this package would use the `@material-ui/styles` package from my app but there are two different instances of the same package which causes the `It looks like there are several instances of "@material-ui/styles" initialized in this application. This may cause theme propagation issues, broken class names and makes your application bigger without a good reason.` error.

I was describing it here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15745 but no one is even trying to help me. It's probably not related directly with the package I'm using but the way how bundlers work. I don't know why Parcel is bundling this package two times instead of just doing it once.

The same problem appears when I try to use Webpack. I always thought that peer dependency will work the way I described.

Here is a reproduction repository: https://github.com/lukejagodzinski/mui-styles-reproduction

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but have you run [`npm ls @material-ui/styles`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html) to see where the dependencies are coming from?

Comment: Yep I've already tried that. Actually I think I've managed to solve it just now :P. Hmm it's really strange but I've just removed `node_modules` from the package and build package again but letting it to throw error. It built the package even though there was an error. Now when I import a package it just works properly. So maybe it's just a problem of adding dependency with the `file:../card` protocol

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and this helped me: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1838#issuecomment-492369750

That basically will remove the duplicated dependency on build time. 
Also be aware that you are using TS, so there's one additional complexity on this issue.